# What is the best way to use List<String> in Realm Android?

Tags: android, realm

I use RealmString alternative to List < String > in Realm Android.
But I have a problem with RealmChangeListener. I use RealmString in many models like Dog, Cat, Chicken in below example. 
But when anyone in that change data, all of them change too.

Ex: When I save Dog -> Dog Change and Cat Change too.

I can fix this problem by use RealmDogString, RealmCatString, RealmChickenString but it duplicates my code. Have anyone better solution?

This is my examples code:

```
public class RealmTestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Context context;
    private Realm realm;

    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_realm_test);

        Stetho.initialize(
            Stetho.newInitializerBuilder(this)
                .enableDumpapp(Stetho.defaultDumperPluginsProvider(this))
                .enableWebKitInspector(RealmInspectorModulesProvider.builder(this).build()).build());

        context = this;

        RealmConfiguration realmConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this).build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfig);
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

        final RealmResults<Dog> puppies = realm.where(Dog.class).lessThan("age", 2).findAll();
        puppies.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<Dog>>() {
          @Override
          public void onChange(RealmResults<Dog> results) {
            System.out.println("XXX Dog ::" + puppies.size());
            Toast.makeText(context, "Dog Change", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            puppies.size();
          }});


        final RealmResults<Cat> puppiesCat = realm.where(Cat.class).lessThan("age", 2).findAll();
        puppiesCat.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<Cat>>() {
          @Override
          public void onChange(RealmResults<Cat> results) {
            System.out.println("XXX Cat  ::" + puppiesCat.size());
            Toast.makeText(context, "Cat Change", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
        });
    }

    public void saveDog(View view) {
        Dog dog = new Dog();
        dog.setName("Bella");
        dog.setAge(1);
        RealmList<RealmString> realmStrings = new RealmList<RealmString>();
        RealmString realmString = new RealmString();
        realmString.setValue("link_Bella.png");
        realmStrings.add(realmString);
        dog.setImage(realmStrings);

        realm.beginTransaction();
        realm.copyToRealm(dog);
        realm.commitTransaction();
    }

    public void saveCat(View view) {
        Cat cat = new Cat();
        cat.setName("Oliver");
        cat.setAge(1);
        RealmList<RealmString> realmStrings_2 = new RealmList<RealmString>();
        RealmString realmString_2 = new RealmString();
        realmString_2.setValue("link_Oliver.png");
        realmStrings_2.add(realmString_2);
        cat.setImage(realmStrings_2);
        realm.beginTransaction();
        realm.copyToRealm(cat);
        realm.commitTransaction();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not an answer, but it is appreciated if you can add the above to https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/575

Comment: Thank @geisshirt. But I can't post because in GitHub say " This conversation has been locked and limited to collaborators".

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I have the powers to unlock conversations :-) I have added a link in the issue to here.

Comment: Thanks @geisshirt, you can do that for me :)

Comment: You should store `List<String>` as a single String field.

Comment: Thanks @EpicPandaForce, nice ideas.

Comment: Technically since Realm 3.0, even with RealmString, the listener would be only called if RaelmChangeListener belongs to RealmString itslef.

Answer (score 1):

Realm for Android supports list of primitives from 4.0.0 version: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/575