# Filter Realm results by String array field

Tags: java, realm

This question is related to the inability to contains a list of primitive types issue[1]. The current, rather weakly documented, solution[2] says to use a custom `RealmString` object. Unfortunately, the solution only shows how to save values When using `RealmString`. How can a nested filter be performed as in the following?

```
class Thing extends RealmObject {
    public RealmList<Tag> tags;
}

class Tag extends RealmObject {
    private String tag;
    public String getTag() { return tag; }
    public void setTag(String tag) { this.tag = tag; }
}

// how do you perform the search here? equalTo, contains?
RealmResults<Thing> things = realm.where(Thing.class).equalTo("tags", searchValue).findAll();
```

1. https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/575
2. [What is the best way to use List<String> in Realm Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39804941/what-is-the-best-way-to-use-liststring-in-realm-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Link Queries](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#link-queries):

```
RealmResults<Thing> things = realm.where(Thing.class)
                                  .equalTo("tags.tag", searchValue)
                                  .findAll();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. That seems to work, but because I have many tags that is not very intuitive. I expected `.includes("tags", searchValue)` or something similar.